# How do I add multiple values to the same key in a TreeMap?

Tags: java, treemaps

My tree Map is

```
Map<String, Double> restrMap = new TreeMap<String, Double>();
```

While adding the below two value to the treeMap, it only shows one. The second value, when comes updates the first one.

```
6, 8.00
6, 5.00
```

How can I add two values for the same key, perhaps in different rows?

Comment: A map is not a table. Its purpose is to find a value by a key. So there is only one value for a key. You can make that value a container of several objects.

Answer (score 5):

If you are adding multiple values to the same key, consider having a Map of Lists.

```
Map<String, List<Double>> restrMap = new TreeMap<String, List<Double>>();
```

Answer (score 2):

A map has only one value associated to a specific key.

If you want several values, you can:

- use Guava's [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)
- use Apache Commons Collections [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html)
- use a `Map<Key, Set<Value>>` or any other collection for the values that would meet your needs

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have multimap, but you could uses another container in the map value.

```
Map<String, List<Double>> restrMap = new TreeMap<String, List<Double>>();
```